# spark scala - How to create a UDT (cassandra user data type [list <UDT>]) from a CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have  a CSV file with ID, ID1, ID2, col1, col2, and col3 fields...I need to group the record based on the ID field and convert it to a UDT list.

```
ex:

ID ID1 ID2 COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4

1   AA  01   A   B   C    D
1   AA  02   A   B   C    D
1   AA  02   B   C   D    E
1   AA  03   A   B   C    D
2   BB  01   A   B   C    D
2   BB  02   A   B   C    D
3   CC  01   A   B   C    D
3   CC  01   B   C   D    E

THE OUTPUT SHOULD BE

1,[{ID1:"AA",ID2:"01"},{ID1:"AA",ID2:"02"},{ID1:"AA",ID2:"03"}]
2,[{ID1:"BB",ID2:"01"},{ID1:"BB",ID2:"02"}]
3,[{ID1:"CC",ID2:"01"}] (grouped by ID; rest of the ID fields in a list array)
```

I tried collect_list / collect_set to group the fields but could not convert them to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using struct(ID1,ID2) ; then followed by collect_list(<struct_col) over (ID)

Comment: Could you please add a code example?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).